# Yii 2, Active Record class does not get ID after save

Tags: php, activerecord, model, controller, yii2

I have two following controller declarations in Yii 2. Former gets the id automatically after the save, whereas latter does not.

This one gets the $test->id automatically after $test->save()

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\test\Test;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function actionAdd()
    {
        $model = new Test;

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save())
        {
            var_dump($model);
            return 'success';
        } else {
            return $this->render('add', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }

    }
}
```

Where this one does not

```
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\customer\Customer;
use app\models\customer\Phone;
use app\models\customer\CustomerRecord;
use app\models\customer\PhoneRecord;

class CustomersController extends Controller 
{
    private function store (Customer $customer)
    {
        $customerRecord = new CustomerRecord();
        $customerRecord->name = $customer->name;
        $customerRecord->birthDate = $customer->birthDate->format('dd-mm-yyyy');
        $customerRecord->notes = $customer->notes;

        echo 'customer before save';
        var_dump($customerRecord);
        $customerRecord->save();
        echo 'customer after save';
        var_dump($customerRecord);


        foreach ($customer->phones as $phone)
        {
            $phoneRecord = new PhoneRecord();
            $phoneRecord->number = $phone->number;
            $phoneRecord->customer_id = $customerRecord->id;           
            $phoneRecord->save();
        }

    }

    private function makeCustomer(CustomerRecord $customerRecord,
            PhoneRecord $phoneRecord) 
    {
        $name = $customerRecord->name;
        $birthDate = new \DateTime($customerRecord->birthDate);
        $customer = new Customer ($name, $birthDate);
        $customer->notes = $customerRecord->notes;
        $customer->phones[] = new Phone($phoneRecord->number);

        return $customer;

    }

    public function actionAdd() 
    {
        $customer = new CustomerRecord;
        $phone = new PhoneRecord; 

        if ($this->load($customer, $phone, Yii::$app->request->post()) && $customer->save())
        {
            $this->store($this->makeCustomer($customer, $phone));
        }

        return $this->render('add', ['customer' => $customer, 'phone' => $phone]);
    }

    private function load (CustomerRecord $customerRecord, Phonerecord $phoneRecord,
            array $post)            
    {
        return $customerRecord->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) 
                and $phoneRecord->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) 
                and $customerRecord->validate()
                and $phoneRecord->validate(['number']);
    }


}
```

Latter code is from a book named "Web Application Development with Yii 2 and PHP" and it uses a transition layer between MVC and active record (if I understand it right).

$customerRecord->update() and $customerRecord->getPrimaryKey() does not help as well.

Any ideas?

P.S. data gets written to the written to the db without Problem.

Comment: Does table has primary key? Is auto_increment enabled for primary key?

Comment: Yes and yes. And they work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using in actionAdd

```
 if ($this->load($customer, $phone, Yii::$app->request->post()) && $customer->save(false ))
```

and function store

```
 $customerRecord->save(false);
```

could be only a validation problem than that prevents the proper conduct of activities, (in this case the saving of the respective model)

Comment: Thanks, that worked like a charm. Thanks a lot :) But new questions arised :) 

- that false parameter disables the validation. Is that correct? 
- If that is so, it means validation has failed previously (or does it?). But that wasn't preventing the model being recorded into the database. Is that the expected behavior? If it is, what does the validation do exactly? 
- How can I get the validation result to see what was wrong?

Comment: Yes the param false disable validation. This is not for production but only for test environment. In this case the validation has effectively failded previous. You must selectively (commenting) evaluate the rule in contrast with you need and correcy the rule or the logic of you app.

Comment: Figured it out. It was a date formatting problem. Now it works without false parameter as well. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If you think my answer and comment are also useful please rate the answer  as useful too.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem when trying to add a reference to a foreign table's auto-increment field. I was manually adding the row and then tried getting $record->id and $record->getPrimaryKey() but both were returning null even after the record was successfully committed to the database.

I overlooked the fact that just because I had an auto-increment field, that I didn't actually have a primary key set on the table. Yii reads the database schema and uses the table information to determine what primary keys there are and subsequently how to update the primary keys in your record after insertion. So even if your ActiveRecord definition has defined a primary key, this is not enough.  Once I added the primary key to the table, everything magically worked!